# PHP and MySQL insert when register, what if register table success but pending table failed

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have 2 tables for user registration. 1 is user, and 2 is pending.
When a user submitted a register form, I have to use two insert and mysql_query() them.
Now I wanna know what if the second one failed? Which must be very disturbing. :-(

User and Email are both unique in the user table. No duplicate data allowed.

Comment: Check before inserting, wrap the whole process in an SQL transaction and rollback if the second query fails. Also, stop using `mysql_*` functions and use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: you can add a column name pending in the user table and you can hold a value in that column as true and false.

Comment: @DCoder He must be a novice programmer, and so using mysql to understand the concepts is ok, later on he can switch

Comment: @Mr.Alien: the mysql extension is outdated and being deprecated. It doesn't make understanding SQL any easier than using PDO or mysqli. All using the mysql extension means is that the OP will learn outdated information that will have to be discarded.

Comment: @outis if you refer any book or tutorial videos for php, mysql, they will always teach you using mysql, and then you can switch to mysqli easily, PDO i s completely different concept, if he's going for OOP, then its suitable for him to use that, and btw mysql extension is still not deprecated, its just not getting updated by the community anymore

Comment: @Mr.Alien: that's because those tutorials are outdated and shouldn't be used, any more than `__autoload` or giving a constructor the same name as its class. There are plenty of more up-to-date tutorials that use PDO. And the extension is *being* deprecated (the phrase used on the dev mailing list is "soft deprecation"); read any of the [manual pages](http://php.net/mysql_query). The only reason it hasn't been deprecated fully is that there's so much old information and old code out there that people keep reading. The PHP devs have wanted to get rid of it for a long time.

Comment: @outis I personally don't use PDO, I use mysqli because I don't find OOP worth learning, sorry to say this I know it's really usefull but I think it is something like cracking a nut using a sledge hammer, I stick to procedural ..

Comment: @Mr.Alien: mysqli is fine. Note that in my original comment I recommended PDO or mysqli. As for OOP, it's not the solution for every problem, but it solves some better than pure procedural, just as FP solves some better than OOP. It sounds like you're falling victim to the [blub paradox](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BlubParadox)

Comment: @outis agreed bro! and yes I saw that but my point was mysql extension is the simplest to get started with ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14239/discussion-between-outis-and-mr-alien)

Answer (score 0):

Use transaction (InnoDB database engine) for writing 2 inserts in. If one insert fail, then rollback the transaction.

For unique data columns use UNIQUE index.

Comment: Thanks for all of you. I'm sure a novice. -_- Now I got to read some books before asking stupid questions. So from now on, InnoDB, mysqli, and transection... and OOP. Thank you again, have a nice day.